# jstree select node

Tags: jquery, jstree

Greetings, 
I am using jsTree to generatate my hierarchical data. JsTree is generated as follows:

```
$(function() {
$("#industries").tree({
        data: {
            type: "json",
            opts: {
                url: "/Admin/GetIndustries/"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

it works find and the jsonresult is something like:

```
[{"attributes":[],"data":{"title":"Adwokaci, Notariusze","id":"1a051101-c3fa-48f2-b2e1-c60d1b67ea22"},"children":[{"attributes":[],"data":{"title":"Kancelarie adwokackie","id":"26d6cff1-3c7f-4a2f-bf5a-422e08127b43"
```

my question is: how can I save id of selected node in some hidden field? I do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#industries").click(function() {
        var tree = $.tree.reference("industries");
        var t = $.tree.focused(); if (t.selected) t.selected; else alert("Select a node first");
        alert(t.id);

    });
```

but it does not work. I get in my alert window "undefined". Can someone please help me?

**EDIT:**
I've changed the jstree instance as follows:

```
$(function() {
$("#industries").tree({
        callback: {
            onselect: function(NODE, TREE_OBJ) {
                    alert(NODE.id);
                }
            },
        data: {
            type: "json",
            opts: {
                url: "/Admin/GetIndustries/"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and i get empty alertt

Comment: IF you have the cookie plugin enabled, the select_node.jsTree event is fired as soon as state is loaded from cookie, how i can capture an event that only if the user selects an item is triggered?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Or just bind the select node:

```
$("#industries").tree({
        callback: {
            onselect: function(NODE, TREE_OBJ) {
                    alert(NODE.id);
                }
            },
        data: {
            type: "json",
            opts: {
                url: "/Admin/GetIndustries/"
            }
        }
    })
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (NODE, REF_NODE) {
            var a = $.jstree._focused().get_selected();
        }
    });
```

Try looking at the variable a for the ID, or NODE. I was actually using REF_NODE to get

Comment: Note that "ui" has to be an included plugin as per https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jstree/zAflwcK5XRQ

Answer (score 7):

I did not check all the answers but saw that you didnt select any so decided to post a method that worked for me

```
 $(function () {
        $("#demo1")
        .bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
                           var selectedObj = data.rslt.obj;
            alert(selectedObj.attr("id") + selectedObj.attr("data"));
             })
```

this is if you want the id and the title of the node. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in your `bind()` function like this:

```
.bind("check_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
    //console.log(data.rslt.obj.attr(\'id\'));

    if (data.rslt.obj !== undefined && data.rslt.obj.attr(\'id\') !== undefined) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "' . Yii::app()->createUrl('adsmanager/adsfields/ajaxappendcategory') . '",
            data: {
                "id" : data.rslt.obj.attr(\'id\'),
                "itemId" : "' . Yii::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id') . '",
            },
            success: function(r) {
                if(r === undefined || r.status === undefined || !r.status) {
                    data.rslt.obj.removeClass(\'jstree-checked\');
                    data.rslt.obj.addClass(\'jstree-unchecked\');
                } else {
                    niceBox(\'ok, checked\');
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return true;
});
```

The same with uncheck action.

Answer (score 0):

Try the callbacks mentioned here: http://www.jstree.com/documentation

It should work something like this:

```
$("#industries").tree({
    //..... your other stuff .....
    callback: {
        onselect: function(NODE, TREE_OBJ) {
                      node_id = NODE.id;
                  }
    }
});
```

Comment: ctrl+f 'callback' 0 results ????? ALso, this syntax is no longer supported, since it's not doing anything.

Comment: @Drew I haven't used this in a while and can't check now. If you're still stuck, open a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've changed your code to use the onselect callback, are you still having problems? I can't tell if your edit means you've solved the problem or not. If you have, you should mark this question as answered.

Personally, I use onchange instead of onselect, but I'm sure either would work. You could also consider using [jquery's data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) features to store values along with an element on the page instead of a hidden field, unless you are wanting submit a form with the value.

But if you need to save it to a hidden field, try something like this:

```
$("#industries").tree({
    //..... your other stuff .....
    callback: {
        onchange: function(NODE, TREE_OBJ) {
             $("#hidden_field").val(NODE.id);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the ids being assigned to any of the HTML objects at the moment?

In my solution I set the id on the attribute of the item, not in the data, which sets the ids on each <li>. Like so:

```
[{"data":"Origination","attributes":{"id":"10"}",children":[
                     {"data":"New Connection","attributes":{"id":"11"}},
                     {"data":"Disconnection","attributes":{"id":"12"}},
                     {"data":"Load Change","attributes":{"id":"13"}},
                     {"data":"Corporate","attributes":{"id":"14"}}
                     ]}]
```

and that has the effect of rendering this HTML (I am also using the jsTree checkbox plugin):

```
<UL class=ltr sizcache="2" sizset="4">
  <LI id=10 class="  open" selected="false"><A class=undetermined href=""><INS>&nbsp;</INS>Origination</A>
  <UL sizcache="2" sizset="0">
    <LI id=11 class=leaf selected="false"><A href=""><INS>&nbsp;</INS>New Connection</A></LI>
    <LI id=12 class=leaf selected="true"><A class=checked href=""><INS>&nbsp;</INS>Disconnection</A></LI>
    <LI id=13 class=leaf selected="false"><A href=""><INS>&nbsp;</INS>Load Change</A></LI>
    <LI style="MARGIN-TOP: 0px" id=14 class="last leaf" selected="true"><A class=checked href=""><INS>&nbsp;</INS>Corporate</A></LI>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Matt, I also put the id in an attributes object, so it gets attached to the li node (example copied from Matt).

```
{"data":"Origination",
 "attributes":{"id":"10"},
 "children":[
   { "data":"New Connection",
     "attributes":{"id":"11"}
   },
   { "data":"Disconnection",
     "attributes":{"id":"12"}
   }
 ]
}
```

Then, in my onselect function, I first wrap the li node in jQuery (the function parameter is not wrapped), then get it's id.

```
    treeObject.callback = {
        onselect: function(liNode, oTree) {
            var id = $(liNode).attr('id');
            var script = ComParentSet.getScript(id);
            script.doXYZ();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#jstree-api').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
    var objNode = data.instance.get_node(data.selected);
    var note;
    note = 'Selected Node Data(Id: <strong>' + objNode.id + '</strong>, Name: <strong>' + objNode.text + '</strong>)'; e = 'Selected Category(Id: <strong>' + objNode.id + '</strong>, Name: <strong id="api-data" data-parent="' + objNode.parent + '" data-id="' + objNode.id + '">' + objNode.text + '</strong>)';

    $('#footer-api').html(note);
});
```

This will get you the selected node details.

[Here is a series of article](http://www.icodefor.net/search/label/jsTree) you should follow if you are using jsTree.